# jquery chessboard-like Sortable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Im using the sortable() function in jquery in order to build something like a "chessboard" in a div. The thing that i want to implement is to have a div with sortable items something like this [sortable example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid) that you can drag and drop them in predefined places (like on chess). In addition to the sortable example i want to do something like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-R5QdBaLScQ8/T5pqwYYHrxI/AAAAAAAAAJk/vvl712vdxnY/s675/divchess.jpg) (suppose that this is a div).

Here is my code so far

```
    <style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
    .class { width: 350px; height: 350px; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>


<div class="demo">

<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: My question is how can i move the sortable items just like the photo ive posted in my question..look at the photo.if i try to leave (3) there it will "snap" back to its position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use **draggable**
Is this what you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/GbQH2/3/

```
var original;
$( "#sortable li" ).draggable({
    grid: [100,100],
    containment:'#demo',
    start:function(event, ui){

        original = $(ui.helper).position();
    }
});
$('#sortable li').each(function(){
    $(this).css({top:$(this).position().top,left:$(this).position().left});
});
$('#sortable li').css({position:'absolute'});

$( "#sortable li" ).bind( "dragstop", function(event, ui) {
    $( "#sortable li" ).each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')) return;
        if(compareOffset($(this).offset(),ui.offset)){
            console.log(original);
            $(this).css({left:original.left,top:original.top});
            console.log($(this).position());
            return;
        }         
    });
});

function compareOffset(offset1, offset2){
    return offset1.top==offset2.top && offset1.left==offset2.left;
}
```

Comment: grid! thats exactly what i want!the only problem that i have with your code is that if you put an element on top to another it stays there.. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: yes, this is a little bit complicated since is not natively handled by jQuery<br>Ithink this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/GbQH2/3/

Comment: Hey ive got another question to this.. is it posible at the start of the drag to disable the snap to grid and then enabled it again at the drag stop??