# Removing white lines in table element

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-development

I wrote a js code to make the table and the tds and trs but there are these weird white lines between and I'm pretty sure that's a problem with one of the CSS properties but I just can't find the thing I need to change.
I am kind of a beginner programmer. Help will be welcome and if you have improvements to the code or maybe just a suggestion or something on how to continue my programing journey I will be very glad  :)

```js
const board = document.getElementById("board");
let black = true;

for(let i = 1; i <= 8; i++){

    let row = document.createElement("tr");
  
    if(black){
        row.classList.add("black");
    }
    else{
        row.classList.add("black");
    }
    black = !black;
  
    board.appendChild(row);

    for(let j = 1; j <= 8; j++){

        let column = document.createElement("td");
      

        if(black){
            row.classList.add("black");
        }
        else{
            row.classList.add("white");
        }
        black = !black;
    
        board.appendChild(column);

    }
}
```

```css
.black {
    background: black;
}

.white { 
    background: white;
}

table { 
    height: 900px;
    width: 900px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, tr {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 112.5px;
    width: 112.5px;
}

td::after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%;
}

.sqr { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chessContainer">
        <table id="board">

        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="chess.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I highly suggest learning CSS grid, this would be so easy to layout using grid. No need for a table.

Comment: structure is wrong

Comment: If you get stuck trying to use tables, give this a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348488/jquery-chessboard-like-sortable-div

Comment: I think it would better for you to learn CSS displaying methods. (flexbox-grid-block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the javascript, you want to append the columns (td) to the row (tr) then append the row to the board.

`board.appendChild(row);` this is your issue. Change it to `row.appendChild(column);`

NOTE: If you right click browser when you run it and look at the way your table is built, you will see that you are creating a `tr` and there is nothing inside the row, then you have 8 `td` tags and the html continues in that manner. This should be the clue to look at.

```js
const board = document.getElementById("board");
let black = true;

for(let i = 1; i <= 8; i++){

    let row = document.createElement("tr");
   // let sqr = document.createElement("div");
    //sqr.classList.add("sqr");

    if(black){
        row.classList.add("black");
    }
    else{
        row.classList.add("black");
    }
    black = !black;
    //row.appendChild(sqr);
    board.appendChild(row);


    for(let j = 1; j <= 8; j++){

        let column = document.createElement("td");
        //let sqr2 = document.createElement("div");
        //sqr2.classList.add("sqr");


        if(black){
            row.classList.add("black");
        }
        else{
            row.classList.add("white");
        }
        black = !black;
       // column.appendChild(sqr2);
        row.appendChild(column);

    }
}
```

```css
.black {
    background: black;
}

.white { 
    background: white;
}

table { 
    height: 900px;
    width: 900px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, tr {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 112.5px;
    width: 112.5px;
}

td::after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%;
}

.sqr { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chessContainer">
        <table id="board">

        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="chess.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```